# hotmail sendmail question

Tags: vb.net, sendmail, hotmail

using VB.NET `System.Net.Mail` I declare

```
Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
```

With a Gmail account and using port 587 I'm able to send emails, it works.

Now I want to use the very same program with a `smtp.live.com` POP server and my Hotmail account.

And there is this "TSL" thing that I can't find no valid sample how to use it.

Admittedly I've found EASendmail as a commercial solution, which I rejected.

Why would I pay for something that's normally included within .NET?

Comment: cracks are free...... ;)

Comment: Your question is voted to be closed because it is not clear. Refer to http://www.systemnetmail.com for examples.

Answer (score 0):

I paid for AfterLogic's MailBee because System.Net.Mail doesn't give you all that one could want from mail object. And haven't looked back since.

As for your question, it is not TSL but TLS. [Googling](http://ask-leo.com/what_are_windows_live_hotmails_pop3_and_smtp_settings.html) a bit reveals pretty standard SMTP settings for live.com. Try them and report back with details if you're still having problems.